# $P(A) = 0.6$, $P(B) = 0.5$, $P(A \cup B) = 0.9$, $P(E) = 1$ calculate: P($(E \backslash A) \cap (E \backslash B))$

Tags: probability

So I am just doing some exercises in my probability book, and there is no sample solutions. Just wanted some feedback on what I think is correct.

We have that:
$P(A) = 0.6$, $P(B) = 0.5$, $P(A \cup B) = 0.9$, $P(E) = 1$, E is the sample space or an event that covers it completely.

And I have to calculate: $P((E \backslash A) \cap (E \backslash B))$

So in the book they have the rule for some events A and B:
$$
(A \cup B)^{c} = A^{c} \cap B^{c}
$$
Where the superscript $c$ denotes the complement.
So I rewrite
$$
P((E \backslash A) \cap (E \backslash B))
$$
to
$$
P(E \backslash (A \cup B))
$$

Because we know that the union has probability $0.9$ from the assignment text, and because of the rule, for some event $A$:
$$
P(E \backslash A) = 1 - P(A)
$$
We get:
$$
P(E \backslash (A \cup B)) = 1 - 0.9 = 0.1
$$
Does this make sense?

Comment: yes that makes perfect sense

Comment: "$E$ is the sample space or an event that covers it completely." Really, both options are not the same.If $E$ is the sample space, your answer is correct. If not, it is not quite correct to say that $A^c=E-A$ (even if the answer is the same )

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo E is the sample space in this case. But often in the analysis I have been involved with, people just pick some random variable and define it to be the sample space, instead of formally defining the sample space.

Comment: @DenLilleMand Yes, but that an event has probability 1 does not mean that it is "everything". You have to be more careful with those things related to measure theory

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Alright, thanks for the advice, I am not sure if I will ever make it deep into measure theory, one can only hope.
I am studying computer science, I think if you know a lot of measure theory, the way we use probability would without a doubt shock you.

Comment: @DenLilleMand However, how to solve the problem is not a mystery. Because you can say that $A^c=(E\cup E^c)-A=(E-A)\cup(E^c-A)$, where this union is disjoint (and thus the probability adds). If $\mathbb{P}(E)=1$ then $\mathbb{P}(E^c)=0$ and, since $E^c-A\subset E^c$, you arrive at $\mathbb {P}(E^c-A)=0$.